# Draw a never-ending line in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, xamarin.ios

I am drawing a line in XNA which I want to never end. I also have a tool that moves forward in X-direction and a camera which is centered at this tool. However, when I reach the end of the viewport the lines are not drawn anymore. Here are some pictures to illustrate my problem:

[image]

At the start the line goes across the whole screen, but as my tool moves forward, we reach the end of the line.

Here are the method which draws the lines:

```
        private void DrawEvenlySpacedSprites (Texture2D texture, Vector2 point1, Vector2 point2, float increment)
    {
        var distance = Vector2.Distance (point1, point2);    // the distance between two points
        var iterations = (int)(distance / increment);       // how many sprites with be drawn
        var normalizedIncrement = 1.0f / iterations;        // the Lerp method needs values between 0.0 and 1.0
        var amount = 0.0f;

        if (iterations == 0)
            iterations = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            var drawPoint = Vector2.Lerp (point1, point2, amount);
            spriteBatch.Draw (texture, drawPoint, Color.White);
            amount += normalizedIncrement;
        }
    }
```

Here are the draw method in Game. The dots are my lines:

```
protected override void Draw (GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        nyVector = nextVector (gammelVector);
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget (renderTarget);
        spriteBatch.Begin ();
        DrawEvenlySpacedSprites (dot, gammelVector, nyVector, 0.9F);
        spriteBatch.End ();

        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget (null);
        spriteBatch.Begin (SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null, camera.transform);
        spriteBatch.Draw (renderTarget, new Vector2 (), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw (tool, new Vector2(toolPos.X - (tool.Width/2), toolPos.Y - (tool.Height/2)), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End ();

        gammelVector = new Vector2 (nyVector.X, nyVector.Y);
        base.Draw (gameTime);
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I'm guessing it has to do with the viewport.width, but I'm not quite sure how to solve it. Thank you for reading!

Comment: I noticed you're using a renderTarget. That could be the source of your problem.

Comment: The problem was still there when I was not using a renderTarget. The reason I am using a renderTarget, is because I don't want my lines to disappear when I am redrawing the tool when it gets moved around.

Comment: If I wrote this, I would not save the screen content across frames, but only the position of line vertices. Then in each frame, I would draw the visible parts. You can always cache some parts, but you will probably need more than one texture for that. Btw, your approach to rendering lines might be easy, but it's horribly inefficient. If you need something more efficient, have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manders/archive/2007/01/07/lines-2d-thick-rounded-line-segments-for-xna-programs.aspx).

Comment: exactly. store coordinates of each line vertice. find a function that will draw you a line using "one pixel" texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read this and thought it would be a fun exercise this morning, so I decided to write this for fun.

The implementation is pretty simple, keep adding lines at the end of each other until the last line is outside of the viewable area.

The following code will draw a line infinitely going right.  As an added optimization, the lines on the left side of the screen are deleted as you pass them.  You could easily make it retain the lines that were there previously, or also create lines going left as well.  I will leave these exercises to you.

Take a look at the following **Line class**, which will define a single line on screen:

```
public class Line
{
    Texture2D Texture;
    Color Color;
    public Vector2 PointA;
    public Vector2 PointB;
    float Width;

    public Line(Vector2 pointA, Vector2 pointB, float width, Color color, Texture2D texture)
    {
        Texture = texture;
        PointA = pointA;
        PointB = pointB;
        Width = width;
        Color = color;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
    {
        float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(PointB.Y - PointA.Y, PointB.X - PointA.X);
        float length = Vector2.Distance(PointA, PointB);
        spritebatch.Draw(Texture, PointA, null, Color, angle, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(length, Width), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }

}
```

I wrote the implementation inside of a game class, since I was speedcoding.  You can see the **Game class** below:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Camera Camera;

    Texture2D LineTexture;
    List<Line> Lines;
    Random Random;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        Camera = new Camera(GraphicsDevice.Viewport, 1f);

        LineTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
        LineTexture.SetData<Color>(new Color[] { Color.White });

        Random = new Random();
        Lines = new List<Line>();
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //handle input
        KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.OemMinus))
            Camera.Zoom -= 0.015f;
        else if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.OemPlus))
            Camera.Zoom += 0.015f;

        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            Camera.Move(new Vector2(0, -30));
        else if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            Camera.Move(new Vector2(0, 30));
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            Camera.Move(new Vector2(-30, 0));
        else if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            Camera.Move(new Vector2(30, 0));


        //check if line is still in viewport - if not remove it
        for (int i = 0; i < Lines.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Lines[i].PointB.X < Camera.Viewport.X)
            {
                Lines.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }

        //if there are no lines, create one to get started
        if (Lines.Count == 0)
        {
            Vector2 p1 = new Vector2(Camera.Viewport.X, Random.Next(Camera.Viewport.Y + 50, Camera.Viewport.Height - 100));
            Vector2 p2 = new Vector2(p1.X + Random.Next(5, 20), p1.Y + Random.Next(-5, 5));
            Line line = new Line(p1, p2, 1, Color.Black, LineTexture);
            Lines.Add(line);
        }

        //Check if we need to add some lines to the right of our last list item
        while (Lines[Lines.Count - 1].PointB.X < Camera.Viewport.X + Camera.Viewport.Width)
        {
            Vector2 p1 = new Vector2(Lines[Lines.Count - 1].PointB.X, Lines[Lines.Count - 1].PointB.Y); ;
            Vector2 p2 = new Vector2(p1.X + Random.Next(5, 20), p1.Y + Random.Next(-5, 5));
            Line line = new Line(p1, p2, 1, Color.Black, LineTexture);
            Lines.Add(line);
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(new Color(30, 90, 150));

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, Camera.View);

        foreach (Line line in Lines)
            line.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

I've also included the **Camera class** for your convenience:

```
public class Camera
{
    private const float zoomUpperLimit = 1.5f;
    private const float zoomLowerLimit = 0.1f;

    private float _zoom;
    private Vector2 _pos;

    private int ViewportWidth, ViewportHeight;

    #region Properties

    public float Zoom
    {
        get { return _zoom; }
        set
        {
            _zoom = value;
            if (_zoom < zoomLowerLimit)
                _zoom = zoomLowerLimit;
            if (_zoom > zoomUpperLimit)
                _zoom = zoomUpperLimit;
        }
    }

    public Rectangle Viewport 
    {
        get
        {
            int width = (int)((ViewportWidth / _zoom));
            int height = (int)((ViewportHeight / _zoom));
            return new Rectangle((int)(_pos.X - width / 2), (int)(_pos.Y - height / 2), width, height);
        }
    }

    public void Move(Vector2 amount)
    {
        _pos += amount;
    }

    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return _pos; }
        set { _pos = value; }
    }

    public Matrix View
    {
        get
        {
            return Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_pos.X, -_pos.Y, 0)) *
                    Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 1)) *
                    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(ViewportWidth * 0.5f, ViewportHeight * 0.5f, 0));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public Camera(Viewport viewport, float initialZoom)
    {
        _zoom = initialZoom;
        _pos = Vector2.Zero;
        ViewportWidth = viewport.Width;
        ViewportHeight = viewport.Height;
    }

}
```